# show all points of carto-point-layer at low zoom-level

Tags: carto, cartocss

I have a Leaflet-map with a carto-layer(points), using the createLayer-method.  It seems that Carto is doing something internally, that not all points are shown at low zoom-levels. Each time zooming in, more points are shown. 
How do i get control of this function, or, respectively how do i ask carto to show all points at low zoom-levels, regardless of collisions and overlapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add [`marker-allow-overlap: true;`](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/cartocss/properties#marker-allow-overlap-boolean) to your CartoCSS code.

[image]